# Is it possible to fetch database records in parts using SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, query-optimization

Is it possible to fetch records in parts?

Following will return 10,000 rows from my db:

Select * from languages

I want to create the select statement that on press of a button it fetches first 1000 rows, then click a button and it fetch next 1000 rows.

How can I do it?

Comment: What RDBMS? Your question is tagged `MySql` **and** `PL/SQL`. Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`LIMIT {offset}, {row count}`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) clause.
This will return the first 1000 records

```
Select * from languages LIMIT 0,1000
```

To get the next 1000 records

```
Select * from languages LIMIT 1000,1000
```

Answer (score 0):

are you just looking for the LIMIT clause?
eg.
    select * from languages limit 1,1000

```
-- later get the next 1000
select * from languages limit 1001, 1000
```

Comment: the offset parameter is inclusive. (Your code query will return rows 1002 - 2001)

Comment: The offset of the first row is 0, not 1. Your LIMIT example will never return the first result